# How do I trim spaces?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have a string and it has spaces at the beginning and at the end. For example:

```
<para> This is a test paragraph </para>
```

Now I have a Regex `"(<\\w+[^<>\\/]*> | <\\/\\w+>)"` that finds any starting and ending spaces between `>` and `<`.

So, if I find any spaces in the beginning, or the end, or maybe both, I want to trim it.

How do I do it?

I was think of:

```
string mainstring = "<para> This is a test paragraph </para>";
string regex1 = "(<\\w+[^<>\\/]*> | <\\/\\w+>)";
string regex2 = "(<\\w+[^<>\\/]*>|<\\/\\w+>)";
mainstring = Regex.replace(mainstring, regex1, regex2);
```

But this wont work.

Also, my string contains multiple lines.

```
string mainstring = "<para> This is a test paragraph </para>";
string regex1 = "(<\\w+[^<>\\/]*> | <\\/\\w+>)";
mainstring = Regex.replace(mainstring, regex1, "");
```

But this removes all the found values and replaces it with `""`.

**Main input:** `"<para> This is a test paragraph </para>"`
**Expected output :** `"<para>This is a test paragraph</para>"`

Comment: If there is a linebreak after open tag or a line break before a close tag, do you want to remove them?

Comment: So, all your tags are paired and never nested?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex to capture the tags and the inner text ignoring spaces just after and just before the tag,

```
(<(\w+)>)\s*(.*?)\s*(<\/\2>)
```

And replace everything with `\1\3\4` which will get rid of unwanted spaces and preserve the rest.

You can widen the character set of tags in case `\w` is not enough for you and can use something like `[\w.-]` etc.

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/TlXvNN/1)**

Check these [C# codes for demo](https://rextester.com/FYSBI21176),

```
string pattern = @"(<(\w+)>)\s*(.*?)\s*(</\2>)";
string substitution = "$1$3$4";
string input = "<para> This is a test paragraph </para>";
Console.WriteLine("Before: " + input);
Regex regex = new Regex(pattern);
string result = regex.Replace(input, substitution);
Console.WriteLine("After: " + result);
```

Prints,

```
Before: <para> This is a test paragraph </para>
After: <para>This is a test paragraph</para>
```

Comment: It replaced all the values with "\1\3\4". In regex101.com the output is perfect but while writing the same in C#, it is not doing as expected.

Comment: Use `$1` instead of `\1` in C#, I've added a C# code demo. Hope that helps.

Comment: Just to make it cleaner: verbatim string literals are good when you do not plan to use string escape sequences. Besides, `/` is not a special regex char and .NET regex does not use regex delimiters.

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi - It replaced a majority of the code but it failed at certain places. Please help me out. I am unable to paste the code here.

Comment: @PrimoChalice: Can you share the parts of sample where it didn't work? Although I suspect something else to be the reason for not being able to make it work. You can add the samples in my demo url

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi - Oh great then. Here is the link: [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/TlXvNN/2)

Answer (score 2):

I think the simpliest approach would be to extract text between tags and then use `Trim()` method on that text:

```
  var mainstring = "<para> This is a test paragraph </para>";
  // First index of >
  var start = mainstring.IndexOf(">") + 1;
  var prefix = mainstring.Substring(0, start);
  // Last index of <
  var end = mainstring.LastIndexOf("<") - 1;
  var suffix = mainstring.Substring(end + 1);
  mainstring = prefix + mainstring.Substring(start, end - start + 1).Trim() + suffix;
```

No need to use regular expressions

Comment: It does not seem to work as it gobbles the first `>`, see https://ideone.com/JxXjiF

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks, you were right :) Corrected

Answer (score 1):

Use [**capturing groups**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) around the parts you want to keep (to replace them with [**backreferences**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/replacebackref.html) in the replacement pattern) and `\s+` to remove whitespace:

```
string mainstring = "<para> This is a test paragraph </para>";
string regex1 = @"(<\w+[^<>/]*>)\s+|\s+(</\w+>)";
mainstring = Regex.Replace(mainstring, regex1, "$1$2");
Console.WriteLine(mainstring);
```

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/zq58PR).

**Details**

- `(<\w+[^<>/]*>)\s+` - Group 1 (`$1`): `<`, 1+ word chars, 0 or more chars other than `<`, `>`, `/` (note you do not have to escape `/` in a .NET regex) and then `>`, and then 1+ whitespaces that are outside of the group
- `|` - or
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `(</\w+>)` - Group 2 (`$2`): `</`, 1+ word chars and a `>`.

Here is the [.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3C%5Cw%2B%5B%5E%3C%3E%2F%5D*%3E%29%5Cs%2B%7C%5Cs%2B%28%3C%2F%5Cw%2B%3E%29&i=%3Cpara%3E%20This%20is%20a%20test%20paragraph%20%3C%2Fpara%3E%0D%0A%3Cpara%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20This%20is%20a%20test%20paragraph%0D%0A%20%20%20%3C%2Fpara%3E&r=%241%242):

[image]